# Browser - Force reload deleting cookies?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, browser, refresh

I have created a page with a select input to change the jQuery UI theme in use. When the theme is changed, it is stored in a cookie. When the page loads, if the cookie exists, the theme is restored, else a default theme is loaded.

My code does work when i refresh the page using F5, but if i force a complete reload using ctrl + F5, it doesn't. Is it a problem in my code or is it a normal effect ?

Here is my code if needed :

```
(function($) {

    $(function() {

        var $themeSelect = $('#themeSelect');

        var initialTheme = $.cookie('theme');

        $themeSelect.on('change', function() {
            var dir = 'jQueryUI/css/' + $themeSelect.val();            
            $('#uiThemeA').attr('href', dir + '/jquery-ui.min.css');
            $('#uiThemeB').attr('href', dir + '/jquery.ui.theme.css');
            $.cookie('theme', $themeSelect.val());
        });

        if(initialTheme !== undefined) {
            $themeSelect.children().each(function(index, element) {
                var $element = $(element);
                if($element.attr('selected')) {
                    $element.removeAttr('selected');
                }
                if($element.attr('value') === initialTheme) {
                    $element.attr('selected');
                }
            }).trigger('change');
        } else {
            $.cookie('theme', $themeSelect.val());
        }

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem :

There was a mistake in my code :

```
if($element.attr('value') === initialTheme) {
    $element.attr('selected');
}
```

Should be :

```
if($element.attr('value') === initialTheme) {
    $element.attr('selected', 'selected');
}
```

And no, **a forced reload doesn't delete cookies**.